# How to implement the subsequences iterator in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to implement an iterator that produces all the [subsequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of an input sequence. Some examples:

```
subsequences "abc"
["","a","b","ab","c","ac","bc","abc"]

subsequences [1,2]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2]]

subsequences [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

subsequences [1,2,3,4]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4],[1,4],[2,4],[1,2,4],[3,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

The Haskell implementation of this is very straightforward:

```
subsequences            :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsequences xs         =  [] : nonEmptySubsequences xs

nonEmptySubsequences         :: [a] -> [[a]]
nonEmptySubsequences []      =  []
nonEmptySubsequences (x:xs)  =  [x] : foldr f [] (nonEmptySubsequences xs)
  where f ys r = ys : (x : ys) : r
```

I just cannot seem to figure out how to recreate this in Rust. I figure it should have the following signature so that it can produce very long sequences without unnecessary memory allocations.

```
fn subsequences<A: Copy>(xs: &[A]) -> impl Iterator<Item=impl Iterator<Item=A>>;
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

```
fn subsequences<A: Copy>(xs: &[A]) -> impl Iterator<Item=impl Iterator<Item=A>+ '_> {
    // return all subsequences of a given sequence
    let n = xs.len();
    (0..1 << n).map(move |i| {
        (0..n).filter(move |j| i & (1 << j) != 0).map(move |j| xs[j])
    })

}
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_subseq() {
        let xs = [1, 2, 3];
        let mut it = subsequences(&xs);
        for _ in 0..8 {
            println!("{:?}", it.next().unwrap().collect::<Vec<_>>());
        }
    }
}
```

Test Output:

```
[]
[1]
[2]
[1, 2]
[3]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I thought about this solution too, but the limitation is the integer size. You cannot have a sequence with more elements than the number of bits in your counter.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that is exactly what [itertools::powerset](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.powerset) does ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7374bd41aa75a261728c3f27dd9e202a)):

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    for s in ['a', 'b', 'c'].into_iter().powerset() {
        println!("{:?}", s);
    }
}

[]
['a']
['b']
['c']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'c']
['b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The returned value is a `Powerset<I>` (being `I` the input type), that implements `Iterator<Item = Vec<<I as Iterator>::Item>>`, and skimming through the [implementation](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/src/itertools/powerset.rs.html#45-84) it looks like it does not preallocate the replies, but it computes them on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in haskell and what you want seems different, isn't the haskell missing the empty subset in `[[a]]` (`[[], [a]]`)?

Anyway, a more or less direct translation to Rust would be something like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80ede813ace2b9d19369859595adca4e)):

```
fn subsequences<A: Copy>(xs: &[A]) -> Vec<Vec<A>> {
    match xs {
        [] => vec![],
        [x] => vec![vec![*x], vec![]],
        [xs@.., x] => {
            subsequences(xs).into_iter()
                .fold(vec![],
                |mut r, ys| {
                    let mut ys0 = ys.clone();
                    ys0.push(*x);
                    r.push(ys0);
                    r.push(ys);
                    r
                })
            }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for s in subsequences(&['a', 'b', 'c']) {
        println!("{:?}", s);
    }
}

['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'c']
['a']
['b', 'c']
['b']
['c']
[]
```

Note that Haskell is optimized to add values at the front of a list, while Rust is best adding to the end of a `Vec` so the order of the output is inverted.

It is not easy avoding the allocations because you must store the values you want to return somewhere. Maybe you could return a value that implements an `impl Iterator<Item: Iterator<A>>` that avoids the allocations but that would require a very different algorithm.

Comment: I elided some of the Haskell for brevity but yes, you're right. I've put it back into the question. Anyway, I agree with the problem of allocations. Actually I realized it is not possible if using recursion because the iterators would need to be boxed anyway. But presumably a recursion can be converted to an iteration so I'm hopeful I'm still going to find a solution that matches my function signature.